# android x86 - play AgeOfZ - app exits on launch

Tags: android-x86

I'm running android x86, in kvm (virtual machine manager) VM, installed from the iso. It loads great, and i have the playstore.

When i install a game "Age of Z" it exits everytime when i launch it ?

How can i debug this further, or is there things that i could try to resolve this.
I am not sure if it requires the screen to be portrait, as that is how the game normally runs on a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Goto "Settings" > "Android-x86 Options" and enable "Enable native Bridge"

Comment: I have the issue, that I can't click anything inside "Age Of Z" on Android_x86. As well after disabling Mouse Integration in VMware.

Comment: Hello. How does this help in debugging?